# Is it possible to bundle data-file into a docker image?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have performed the following steps,

1. docker run -d --name demo-mongo -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=testdb mongo ** to create a new mongodb container
2. Create data-base inside the running container, by connecting to it using a mongo client
3. docker commit demo-mongo demo-mongo-updated ** create image from the running container

However, docker does not by default (which seems obvious) retain the data of the newly created data-base (likely to be retained in /data/db) in the newly created image.

Is it possible by any means to preserve the state of a container while creating an image from the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a volume that points to a host directory and mount it to the container:

```
docker run -v <PATH_TO_THE_HOST_DIR>:/data -d --name demo-mongo -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=testdb mongo
```

The next time you create a mongo container pointing to the same host path, it will be available on the container.

Comment: Thank you already for your answer. However, a volume is specific for a host. By mounting all containers in the same host to a common volume will enable me to share the data between those containers. However if I try to run it on a separate host it will no longer work. Is there a way to bundle the information in the volume data into the an image created from that container?